# Reading data from a text file (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a feature for my Discord Bot that stores usernames for different gaming platforms like; Steam, Battle.net, Epic Games, etc. I'd like whenever I am to execute a specific command and mention a user in the guild, It would read the text file and send all of the usernames for each launcher associated with their discord account from a text file in an embed. I am unsure how I am supposed to create a command like this since I do not have experience with logging information in Python.

I have a bit of an idea i have created

```py
@client.command()   
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)   
async def connections(ctx, member: discord.Member):    
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title="CONNECTIONS",
        description="Connections associated with **"+ str(member) + ("**."),
        color=0xfffffD
    )     
    embed.add_field(name="Steam", value="steam_name", inline=False)     
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Everytime I mention a user at the end of the command, It should open a file and look for that user in the file, then it should find the connections associated with it like `steam_name`

If possible, I'd like to get assistance with the creation of this feature.

Thanks, Horizon

Comment: Do you have any code which you have tried?

Comment: @JacobLee I have a bit of an idea i have created

`@client.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
  async def connections(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    embed=discord.Embed(title="CONNECTIONS", description="Connections associated with **"+ str(member) + ("**."), color=0xfffffD)
    embed.add_field(name="Steam", value="steam_name", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)`

Everytime I mention a user at the end of the command, It should open a file and look for that user in the file, then it should find the connections associated with it like `steam_name`.

Comment: If you could, please add it to your question, as it will be easier to read.

Comment: @JacobLee done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend against using a .txt file to store information that you will be extracting or updating. I recommend using a JSON file. JSON format is especially good for storing small amounts of information in an object oriented style. Look at this quick example:

```
"Spinduck#1704" : {

    "Epic Games" : "Spinnyskull",
    "Steam" : None,
    "Origin" : "Spinduck5384",
    "Xbox" : "Sppppiiiinn"

},
"Papa Frita#1973" : {

    "Epic Games" : None,
    "Steam" : None,
    "Origin" : None,
    "Xbox" : "PapaFrita"

}
```

This makes it easier to extract, update, and generally work with storing information. Read more about Python & JSON here with some of these resources:

https://realpython.com/python-json/

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/

Comment: Sure I’ll give it a try, I’ll let you know if I have more difficulties, Thanks :)

Comment: How would I be able to check and find the list in the file associated with the user in the guild who executed the command?

Comment: You could use a for loop to go through the JSON file and check if any of the instances in the file match the person who called the command's username.